Why does ctypes also load standard C library functions and how could I prevent that?
EDIT: The problem was completely misdiagnosed and was related to linking rather than ctypes itself (the libc is implicitly linked with gcc) and I found an actual solution somewhere else. Hence the duplicate flag.


Loading a homemade shared library with ctypes seems to provide access to standard C library functions somehow.
Why?
I would've expected some kind of AttributeError when trying the MRE below.

How could I restrict this behavior (if possible)?

[tiebreaker] : How does a function name resolve when trying to access it and if my homemade library redefines a standard C library function?



Context and motive:
From what I understand of the documentation it should return a representation of a loaded shared library. But it looks like it's behaving as something more/else than that.
I encountered this behavior while working on my own implementation of some standard C library functions, which caused unexpected results while trying to test it through python tools using ctypes.
The main problem is that editing my code doesn't have any impact on the behavior of the loaded foreign functions and the tests results. Now it looks clear that my tests were actually running the system's functions rather than my own ones.
While using different symbols (such as prepending a prefix to my homemade function names) is an easy workaround, I would really like to understand why this access to functions I never explicitly used or included is provided by ctypes apparently out of nowhere.
I found no trace of such behavior in the ctypes documentation.

MRE:

test.py

#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ctypes
import os

my_lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.abspath("libfoo.so"))

# I expect this to work (It does).
print(f"{my_lib.foo = }")
# I expect this to fail (It doesn't).
print(f"{my_lib.strncmp = }")
# I expect this to fail (It does).
print(f"{my_lib.bar = }")


foo.s:

    global foo

foo:
    ret


shell session:

$ make
nasm -f elf64 -o foo.o foo.s
gcc -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
$ nm -a libfoo.so
0000000000000000 a 
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004000 d __dso_handle
0000000000003e48 d _DYNAMIC
00000000000010f4 t _fini
00000000000010f0 T foo
0000000000000000 a foo.s
0000000000003fe8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000001000 t _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000004008 d __TMC_END__
$ ./test.py
my_lib.foo = <_FuncPtr object at 0x75a09cb3e140>
my_lib.strncmp = <_FuncPtr object at 0x75a09cb3e200>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vmonteco/code/MREs/MRE_ctypes_give_access_to_stdlib/./test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(f"{my_lib.bar = }")
  File "/home/vmonteco/.pyenv/versions/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/home/vmonteco/.pyenv/versions/3.10.14/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /home/vmonteco/code/MREs/MRE_ctypes_give_access_to_stdlib/libfoo.so: undefined symbol: bar
$ ldd libfoo.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007610a363b000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007610a341d000)
        /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007610a363d000)
$ readelf -ld libfoo.so

Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 8 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000428 0x0000000000000428  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000 0x0000000000001000
                 0x0000000000000101 0x0000000000000101  R E    0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000 0x0000000000002000
                 0x0000000000000004 0x0000000000000004  R      0x1000
  LOAD           0x0000000000002e38 0x0000000000003e38 0x0000000000003e38
                 0x00000000000001d0 0x00000000000001d8  RW     0x1000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000000002e48 0x0000000000003e48 0x0000000000003e48
                 0x0000000000000180 0x0000000000000180  RW     0x8
  NOTE           0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000000200
                 0x0000000000000024 0x0000000000000024  R      0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x0000000000002e38 0x0000000000003e38 0x0000000000003e38
                 0x00000000000001c8 0x00000000000001c8  R      0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn 
   01     .init .text .fini 
   02     .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     
   07     .init_array .fini_array .dynamic .got .got.plt 

Dynamic section at offset 0x2e48 contains 20 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
 0x000000000000000c (INIT)               0x1000
 0x000000000000000d (FINI)               0x10f4
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x3e38
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x3e40
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       8 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x228
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x2e0
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0x250
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              111 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x380
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             168 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x360
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         1
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x350
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          3
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
$ 


[Addendum:] Versions and system info:

uname -a: Archlinux (Linux vmonteco-P15 6.10.10-arch1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu, 12 Sep 2024 17:21:02 +0000 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
python: Python 3.10.14
nasm: NASM version 2.16.03 compiled on May  4 2024
gcc: gcc (GCC) 14.2.1 20240910
ld: GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.43.0


C doesn't have namespaces.

@wim I'm not directly using any C here though (would it have behaved differently if the system's .so files were all made with something else than C? Or are you talking about the CPython implementation perhaps?).

Why do you care?  What's the risk?

Can't reproduce (on Ubuntu 20). What's your OS, Python version?

@TimRoberts Hi,
TL;DR: I'm curious and I'd like to know.
Context: I was stuck for a while on a bug that was caused by name collision (I'm re-implementing some standard C library functions). Adding a prefix to the function names would be a workaround but if there's a way to restrict this behavior I'd be interested.
Also I didn't find anyting in the doc about it and I'd like to know how ctypes actually works (it would've actually been useful knowledge if I had it in first place in that specific case as I really was stuck).

@CristiFati I made an addendum.

You may want to raise this question over on https://github.com/python/cpython/issues, because if ctypes causes naming collisions, that's a bug.

@vmonteco Can you also show the runtime linking and the elf table please (edit into your question the outputs of ldd libfoo.so and readelf -ld libfoo.so)

@wim I added it. It looks like that libc actually is involved and that the problem should therefore be from my way of building my shared library (cf. the part where I run make) and not from ctypes as I initially (wrongly) assumed.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans To be fair it's more like the standard functions are called while I tried to build a library that contain my own with the same name. Which is probably caused by the way I build the library after all.

Could I ask you to update your post with an explanation of why this is a problem though? Because not all behaviour is a problem: what problem is there with a function that gets compiled into your library to be there?  (you've put some, but not all, details in comments, please put those in your post instead and then just structure it as a normal "explain what you set out to do, show the code you wrote, explain what's wrong with that code and why that's important, and explain what debugging/(re)searching you already did" post. No need for hrules, addenda, etc.)

IIUC this is just normal? The way languages like C++ achieve namespaces is by name mangling the symbols. But if you're just linking together a bunch of C shared objects, you have to do your own naming convention to avoid symbol name clashes (like using name prefixes or whatever). The pain of managing one big global namespace like this is why Python has module namespaces, and why the Zen of Python says "Namespaces are one honking great idea".

I note that you're doing the linking with gcc, because it is convenient, of course.  If you did the linking by invoking ld directly, you could probably avoid dragging in glibc.  Now, I'm not saying it will be easy to determine the proper ld command line...

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Done but I didn't add code as the MRE probably provides enough information now imho.
As Tim and wim hinted, this is likely a linking rather than a ctypes problem anyway.
Therefore a valid answer could probably be "This isn't a ctypes-related issue but a linker-related one" and I guess that the actual problem would be "How could I prevent glibc to be implicitly linked?" and that such question would probably deserve a whole new post I could reference here if that's OK in according to the SO etiquette (if there's not already such a post).

Absolutely, but that still doesn't answer the underlying question: this is an interesting thing to happen but what was the problem? Because "I encountered this behavior while working on my own implementation of some standard C library functions" is doing a lot of heavy lifting: what actual thing were you doing? (Because without the concrete use-case, this might even be an XY problem, even if the problem is super interesting and spans two generally unrelated technologies).

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I really apologize for the numerous edits/comments and my difficulties for getting your point.
I'm not sure my case even qualify as what you call a "problem" actually. I had the behavior I described with my last edit (editing code didn't impact the tests results after building my own lib), the cause (my tests were running the libc functions rather than my own ones) and the workaround. My remaining motive for this post was mostly the wish to understand and explain what was happening and possibly a cleaner way than the workaround to prevent access to libc functions.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans In the end I briefly explained in a note why my question is actually a duplicate of another one I found my answer in and flagged my post accordingly.
